# Logging to an arbitrary framework specified at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I'm developing a component where one of the requirements is that it has no compile dependencies on my company's proprietary code. Another requirement is that it needs to log using our proprietary logging framework.

I am wondering if there's an interface, preferably in the .net framework that I could use to implement an adapter to our logging framework that would allow me to load it up at runtime using reflection. Other users of the code that might want to use something like log4net would repeat this process.

I'm also open to other solutions that involve a runtime dependency. My fallback is to just create a branch in source control that has the logging dependency and publish a different branch that doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I setup something similar for a third party application.  One plan of attack is to use the adapter pattern and a selector (factory pattern or whatever) to select the concrete adapter required at runtime.  In my case, I did reference the 3rd party DLL which is not a problem when the DLL is not available because of JIT late binding.

However, because you say "compile time requirement" it appears that referencing a DLL is not an option.  In which case I suggest you look at [AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event which you can hook into and supply a path to DLL's (like a network location).  AssemblyResolve can introduce a performance hit on your App.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you will inevitably need some of the logging interface(s) to be shared between your company's porprietary logging framework and the new component.  If so, you could put those interfaces on a separate assembly which both your company's logging framework and your new component will reference, then use [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) to do IoC for you.  This of course will involve some modification to your existing logging framework if not already designed with MEF in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to use the Trace framework in .net. You still need to implement an interface, but this interface is common to the framework and not to a specific project. Also, many logging frameworks implement it already (like NLog).

See `TraceListeners`